# Lecture notes in computer science author information

Tags: templates, lncs

I submitted a paper to a conference that uses the LNCS template, and I honestly have no idea how to insert author and institute information for the camera ready paper. I have read the typeinst document but the template just does not have the `\author` tag, if anyone can help I will be very grateful.

Comment: `llncs` class is derived from `article.cls` so it does have `\author` and `\institute`

Comment: @Johannes_B: Done so

Comment: @Johannes_B: Ah, you mean that. No, that's an invention of `llncs` -- I changed my statements in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `llncs` class is derived from `article.cls` so it does have the `\author` macro. It provides an`\institute` macro as well, but `\date` isn't used apparently.

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\author{Ann Elk (Mrs.) and Mr. Arthur Gumby (Brain Surgeon)}
\title{Theory of Brontosaurs}
\date{30th of February 2016}
\institute{Ministry of Silly Walks}

\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents


\section{Theory on Brontosaurs} \label{theory}


\begin{enumerate}
  \item Brontosaurs were large
  \item Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again on the other end.
\end{enumerate}


\section{Excavations of  Brontosaurs} \label{excavations}

After we stated the theory in \cref{theory} we want to provide you with the most exciting rules of excavating a Brontosaur.

This is the basic strategy:

\begin{itemize}
  \item Dig a hole
  \item Throw away anything that does not really resemble a Brontosaur
  \item In the very end you should have at least some parts of a Brontosaur
\end{itemize}

\section{Results} \label{results}


\backmatter

% Other stuff here

\end{document}
```

[image]